# Grep process crash signal on Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I'm trying to debug my application on Mac OS X Mountain Lion using a bash script which is used to open the application with several input methods. Though I would like to the script to quit running with a short description what happened, if it encounters any error signals (without set -e).

Script is constructed in a following manner:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
...

while true
do
  for input in $INPUTS 
  do
    /path/to/app $input 2> mylog.log &
    sleep 2

    tail -2 /private/var/log/system.log | grep $ERROR &&
     echo $input &&
     exit 1;

    test $? -gt 127 &&
     echo $input &&
     exit 2;

    # nothing happened, kill the app and continue with a new test
    pkill -9 app
  done
done
```

And I've tried to debug the script by manually sending

```
pkill -SIGSEGV app
```

in Terminal.
I'm trying to get the script to print the output to the command line (hence the '&' in the app command) and also to the log file (2>), but it looks like if a crash occurred, it doesn't print the application log properly neither to the file nor terminal and the script just keeps running. Also, somehow the grep from system.log does not catch the crashes.

What would be a better option to monitor and catch application crashes in a shell script on Mac? I've done similar tests on Linux and they worked fine.

EDIT: I am also open for suggestions on other methods for monitoring crashes than a shell script. :-)

Comment: Is the app a Cocoa-based app?  If so shouldn't you be using `open(1)` to start it? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Comment: I am in an understanding that when using open() to start the application, it does not output STDOUT/-ERR to the Terminal in same manner as it does with the straight path to the app. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You might be right; I don't know.  I avoid this issue entirely by using by own logging framework (well a simple class) which write to my own log file.  I catch exceptions/signals and write them to the log file too.  Perhaps that would be a better approach for you?